# Handling Page.Response object in a custom class

Tags: jquery, asp.net, exception, asp.net-2.0

I have a custom class, Customer. I want to show a JQuery message on exception. I am attempting following class but the problem is that `Page.Response` object is unavailable in a custom class.

How to modify the exception line in below given code? I have a separate class named as: `MyErrorHandler`, that stores all the methods for error handling. Code of both the classes is given below:

```
public sealed class Customer
{

     public void FillList()
     {
        try
        {
                .....
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             MyErrorHandler.GetScript(Page.Response,ex.Message.ToString());
        }
}

public static class MyErrorHandler
{
    public static void GetScript(System.Web.HttpResponse r, string customErrorMessage)
    {
        r.Write("<script type='javascript'>$.msg({ content : '" + customErrorMessage + "' });</script>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HttpContext.Current.Response`

Comment: I tried that but the code is not executing. No JQuery message box on screen.

Comment: @RPK that may be another issue.

Comment: First of all confirm whether the <script> block is being output to the HTML. That will then tell you if the issue lies with your ASP.NET code or your jQuery.